# What is this B-52 carrying?

Tags: missiles

Source:(en.wikipedia.org)[image]They look like fighter jets attached to both wings, but can't really tell what they are. What are these objects on the wings?

Comment: This is the picture from Wikimedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:B-52_with_two_D-21s.jpg. That picture appears on three wikipedia pages, each one captioned with a description of what is under the wings and a link to the [Lockheed D-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_D-21) page. Please take the time to read the captions for photos you're looking at before turning to Stack Exchange for help.

Comment: @Ethan Greg is right. Please do take some time to go through the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are [Lockheed D-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_D-21) drones, an an American Mach 3+ reconnaissance drone. Here is a close photo.

[image: D-21 Drone]

"[B-52 with D-21](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:B-52_with_D-21.jpg#/media/File:B-52_with_D-21.jpg)" by US Air Force - http://roadrunnersinternationale.com/d-21/D-21_historial.html. Licensed under Public Domain via [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

The D-21s were initially launched from [Lockheed A-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_A-12), the predecessor of SR-71, but were switched over to B-52 after a fatal accident.